# specify object fields are a property of an enum

Tags: typescript

How can I type the following structure:

```
const fields: any = {
  [AuthForms.LoginForm]: ['email', 'password'],
  [AuthForms.ForceChangePasswordForm]: ['password', 'confirmPassword'],
  [AuthForms.ForgottenPasswordForm]: ['email'],
  [AuthForms.ResetPasswordForm]: ['email', 'password', 'confirmPassword']
};
```

I have tried below but cannot quite get the syntax right

```
const fields: { [keyof AuthForms]: string[] } = {
  [AuthForms.LoginForm]: ['email', 'password'],
  [AuthForms.ForceChangePasswordForm]: ['password', 'confirmPassword'],
  [AuthForms.ForgottenPasswordForm]: ['email'],
  [AuthForms.ResetPasswordForm]: ['email', 'password', 'confirmPassword']
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, you should be able to leave off the type annotation entirely, and use the type inferred by TS. That's what I'd personally do, but if you can't for whatever reason...

Index signatures (the `{ [key: string]: SomeType }` syntax) only accepts the types `string` and `number` for the key. In order to specify specific keys, you'll need to use a [mapped type.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)

Remember: to specify the type for a key of `SomeEnum`, you only need to type `SomeEnum`, so no `keyof` is needed here.

```
const fields: { [K in AuthForms]: string[] } = {
```

You can also opt for the more readable `Record` type, which was made for simple cases like this. This does the same as the above:

```
const fields: Record<AuthForms, string[]> = {
```